# Backup with Deja Dup Backup Tool

Tags: 18.04, backup

Here, I found an instruction on a backup with the built-in backup tool of Ubuntu: https://www.howtogeek.com/108869/how-to-back-up-ubuntu-the-easy-way-with-dj-dup/

However, I was just wondering that if I backed up my entire home folder to an external USB drive, would also all the installed packages and programs (Python3, pip, Opera, ...) be saved in the backup file?

And can I save the backup on a USB where there is an iso file and with which I installed Ubuntu?
The USB flash drive has already been formatted.

Furthermore: How much space do I approximately need for the backup, online I read sth about 3 GB?

Answer (score 1):

- `deja-dup` does not back up your programs if you back up only your home folder.
- How much space you need depends on how big your home folder is.
- You can save the backup on any media that is big enough and properly
  formatted

Comment: How can I set up deja-dup in such a way that also programs (Python, pip3, Opera, ...) are included. Frankly, I don't need a file backup, but a program backup. Thank you!

Comment: I used to recommend aptik for that but now it's a paid tool. There are a number of questions on this site about that sort of thing.