# Backup such that all programs are saved as well

Tags: 18.04, backup

I just recently found out here that the Deja Dup Backup tool does not backup the programs (Python, pip3, Opera, ...): [Backup with Deja Dup Backup Tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220067/backup-with-deja-dup-backup-tool)

Therefore, I would like to ask you whether you know which free and open-source options there are for doing a backup of programs. (Please note that I do not really need a backup of files.)

Comment: Debian-based systems, including Ubuntu, are designed so that most users do not need to backup applications. Applications (and their dependencies) can be easily installed at any time.

Answer (score 0):

[rsync](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/rsync.1.html) and its many GUIs and interfaces is very popular. Some other packages (and this is not a complete list) include:

- [Amanda](https://www.zmanda.com/downloads.html)
- [Areca](http://www.areca-backup.org/)
- [BackInTime](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime/blob/master/README.md)
- [Bacula](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bacula/)
- [BackupNinja](https://labs.riseup.net/code/projects/backupninja)
- [BackupPC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/backuppc/)
- [Borg Backup](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
- [Box Backup](https://github.com/boxbackup/boxbackup)
- [Burp](https://burp.grke.org/)
- [Duplicity](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/duplicity.1.html)
- [fwbackups](http://www.diffingo.com/oss/fwbackups/download)
- [kbackup](http://kbackup.sourceforge.net/)
- [Lucky Backup](http://luckybackup.sourceforge.net/)
- [Restic](https://restic.net/)
- [rclone](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/rclone.1.html)
- [rsnapshot](https://rsnapshot.org/)
- [Simple Backup Suite](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sbackup/)
- [Simple Linux Backup](http://simplelinuxbkup.sourceforge.net/)
- [Urbackup](https://www.urbackup.org/download.html)

If you ever decide you need absolutely, positively, need a copy of the entire system, [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) is very popular.

Whenever you backup, always, always, verify the backup, to make sure what is written to the backup is the same as the original source file; and, always, always, backup twice to make sure if there's a failure with the drive, tape, or cloud you wrote to, there's another copy safely saved elsewhere.